# TinyMCE Default Font not passing on form submit

Tags: css, email, tinymce, html-email

I'm using TinyMCE as the editor for creating an HTML form for people to be able to send HTML emails.

Everything seems to work absolutely fine so when you submit the form any editing you do sends through, however the default font it's using is Times and I would much rather it were Ariel.

I've created a CSS template for it to use and it's working within the TinyMCE editor, but when I submit the email it's defaulting back to Times!

Any ideas how to get it to pass Ariel like it's showing in the editor?

Comment: how do you set the font in the editor?

Comment: In the content.css [link](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:content_css)

Comment: Is that not something to do with the email browser rather than MCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case your font won't be usable in another context as long as you don't apply your css there too (see the settings of your email client).

Comment: That would make sense - I'll give that a whirl